How do I Incorporate Dependency Injection for Classes with Constructor Arguments in C#?
Given the following code:
public interface ISomeClient;

public class SomeClient : ISomeClient
{
  SomeClient(string clientID, string clientSecret) {
    _clientID = clientID;
    _clientSecret = clientSecret;
  }
}

public class SomeWrapper {
  SomeWrapper(ISomeClient someClient) {
    _someClient = someClient;
  }
}

This code should allow dependency injection, yet I don't like how the dependency, 'Some Client', requires arguments. This doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing it. What is the right way to do this type of separation while making it easy for users to use 'SomeWrapper'?
The solutions I have considered are:

Pass in the arguments when instantiating the 'SomeWrapper' class
Create a factory class and use the factory class to instantiate the object with the constructor arguments
Use a separate method to pass in the arguments outisde the constructor
Merge the classes


This question is similar to: Dependency injection, inject with parameters. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is SomeClient considered configuration? In which case you should follow the "options pattern".

^^ Options Pattern

"I don't like how the dependency, 'Some Client', requires arguments. This doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing it." You need to be more precise here. Having a class specify its required arguments via the constructor is a very common approach that allows the class to guarantee it to be correctly and completely initialized upon creation. I, therefore, believe that there are some constraints in your code base that you forgot to specify. Without this extra information, every answer is just speculation. Please update your question to include the missing context.

If you have some kind of runtime configuration values for a service you normally provide them via an Azure Key Vault, appSettings.json or environment variables. For all of them ASP core has a configuration provider which can be used and you can also use different sources in any desired order.
When this is prepared you can take these configuration values and put them into a simple DTO class which will be encapsulated and registered in DI by IOptions<T>. Then you can receive these objects via DI in your constructor.
A good starting point is this article from Andrew, that also describes some common pitfalls, when setting these things up.
While this is probably a link only answer it should give you enough buzzwords for further searching the right solution in your case.
